# Replace comma and full stop between square brackets in java with Empty String

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace the following string

```
([S Creatine]+[b.gfr])-0.32+[c,gd]*1000,00
```

with

```
([S Creatine]+[bgfr])-0.32+[cgd]*1000,00
```

I have a regex that only replace Dashes within brackets with underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[.,](?=[^\[]*\])
```

You can try this.Replace by `empty space`.See demo.the `lookahead` will make sure the `.,` being captured have a `]` without `[` ahead of them.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/10

Comment: Its working fine but how can we make sure that if the "." is followed by and preceded only by  alphabets like this [a.b] not with[3.4]?

Comment: @XeshanJ use `([a-zA-Z])[.,](?=[a-zA-Z][^\[]*\])` and replace by `$1`